# Error in mechanize python: no form matching nr 0

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to webcrawl a [website](http://dbaasp.org/prediction), however, I am getting the following error:

```
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 0.
```

The script is as follows:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("http://dbaasp.org/prediction")
br.select_form(nr = 0)

## See what is available on this web page:
for f in br.forms():
    print f
```

How can this be ameliorated? Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to improve? The page you're crawling doesn't contain any form.

Comment: Since it is not a form, is there any way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle this error in your Python script, just put try/except around your loop.

```
try:
    for f in br.forms():
        print(f)
except mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError as e:
    print("Sorry no form found on this page", e)
```

Answer (score -1):

The page you are accessing doesn't have any  html  element on it but use the  tag directly. You need to nest it inside

```html
 <form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

Comment: how can you embed this in the script?